# get request with basic authentication in swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

How to fetch the data in json with basic auth? I want to display the data in dictionary from my sample code, how to do so?

```
     let username = "user"
     let password = "pass"

     let loginString = String(format: "%@:%@", username, password)
     let loginData = loginString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
     let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedString()

     // create the request
     let url = URL(string: "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.com:111/customer")!
     var request = URLRequest(url: url)
     request.httpMethod = "GET"
     request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

     // fire off the request
     // make sure your class conforms to NSURLConnectionDelegate
     let urlConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure if this is what you're looking for. But when you get a response you can try this:

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseObject as! Data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any]
```

print(json)

Comment: the response your getting is nil? what does your response object look like when you print it?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) in stead of URLRequest. Here is an example of the request:

```
 let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization": defaults.string(forKey: "apiKey")!]

    Alamofire.request("https://../getBeacons", method: .get, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { (responseObject) -> Void in

            if responseObject.result.isSuccess {
                let resJson = JSON(responseObject.result.value!)
                print(resJson)
                for (_, subJson) in resJson["data"] {
beaconData.id.append(subJson["id"].intValue)
beaconData.id.append(subJson["min"].intValue)
beaconData.id.append(subJson["maj"].intValue)

}
            }
            if responseObject.result.isFailure {
                let error : Error = responseObject.result.error!
                print(error)
            }
    }

}
```

At the top create a struct with arrays which will be holding your data received from the webservice.

```
 struct beaconData {
    static var id = [Int]()
    static var maj = [Int]()
    static var min = [Int]()
}
```

You can retrieve the data using:

```
beaconData.id[index]
```